# How to stop auto button click on F5 and page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

In my ascx control I have a button in which I am calling a event handler, and from that event handler I am calling the a method which is in a presenter

on ascx page

```
   public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Add;

   protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Add != null)
             Add(sender, e);

    }
```

on presenter

```
  AddListView.Add += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)//AddListView is a Interface
  {
    Add();

  };
```

when I am clicking on btnAdd its working fine and record is getting added, but when I am refreshing the browser page, by F5 and mouse click again btnAdd is getting fire. I tried to use

```
   // Page refresh F5 btn press
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        object[] AllStates = (object[])savedState;
        base.LoadViewState(AllStates[0]);
        _refreshState = bool.Parse(AllStates[1].ToString());
        _isRefresh = _refreshState == bool.Parse(Session["__ISREFRESH"].ToString());
    }

    // Page refresh F5 btn press
    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        Session["__ISREFRESH"] = _refreshState;
        object[] AllStates = new object[2];
        AllStates[0] = base.SaveViewState();
        AllStates[1] = !(_refreshState);
        return AllStates;
    }
```

Then its working fine but after the refresh I am unable to click on btnAdd again, for click on btnAdd, again I am doing refresh then its working fine..

I am calling this control on some other control and in that I have a Datalist on clicking on item page will postback again.

How to stop auto button click on F5 or page refresh without clicking on btnAdd.

Please someone help me..

Comment: Check this link Detect Browser Refresh Avoid events fire in ASP.NET. [see here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/04/detect-browser-refresh-to-avoid-events.html) Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that after you insert the record is better to make a redirect to the same page and avoid all that.

Comment: but not solving my problem fully, I am adding the item in datalist and when I am clicking on datalist item, postback call issue is coming..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple `Response.Redirect` is fine. It basically turns the initial POST to a different GET request. This works as long as you persist all the POSTed pieces of information. Otherwise they will no more be available, obviously.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we are in Default.aspx here!
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

This does not always work and does indeed have drawbacks. Moreover, it isn't too sophisticated this way. Working with the Routing Framework might get you smoother URLs.